# Is .NET BinaryReader always little-endian, even on big-endian systems?

Tags: .net

Microsoft documentation on BinaryReader for ReadUnt32 (for example) states: Reads a 4-byte unsigned integer from the current stream using little-endian encoding. However, is this always correct, even on big-endian systems?

Comment: Uhm, well [Windows only runs on little-endian machines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/07/426334.aspx) and so does Microsoft's .NET framework. Mono might be a different story.

Comment: @Christian.K: Wrong. The XBox 360 is big endian.

Comment: @Jason Wow, looks like I was too "focused" (not to say narraw-minded) here. Thanks.

Comment: There's little reason to assume the MSDN article is wrong.  It is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is certainly a hint that implementors on other platforms should use little-endian encoding, and [Mono seems to respect this](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid4083672E4B426989ECED8C0C517B0327B94BC1CB.aspx):

```
public virtual uint ReadUInt32() {
FillBuffer(4);

return((uint) (m_buffer[0] |
           (m_buffer[1] << 8) |
           (m_buffer[2] << 16) |
           (m_buffer[3] << 24)));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Directly from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readuint32.aspx) for `BinaryReader.ReadUInt32`:

> `BinaryReader` reads this data type in little-endian format.

Note that there is no qualification about the underlying endianness of the machine. It doesn't matter if the underlying system is big endian (say XBox 360), `BinaryReader` will read in little endian.

In fact, if you tear apart the source you'll see:

```
public virtual long ReadInt64() {
    this.FillBuffer(4);
    uint num = (uint) (((this.m_buffer[0] |
              (this.m_buffer[1] << 0x08)) |
              (this.m_buffer[2] << 0x10)) |
              (this.m_buffer[3] << 0x18));
    return num;
}
```

showing very clear it ignores endianness.

Now, what *will* vary from little endian to big endian machines is `BitConverter.ToUInt32`. The output will respect the underlying endianness of the machine.