# Passing byte[] from Android App to C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, sockets, byte

Im building a C#, WPF and Android application, mostly for training, but either way, the issue that I have is the follow:

When I execute the followed code WPF app, it saves the desire file from the disk to the desktop, but the problem comes when I try to do the same from the Android application, I do get connected to Console application, but the `byte[]` apparently are not the same format, maybe I miss something, or I'm going something wrong.

---

***Convert Image to byte array function: C#***

```
 private static byte[] ImageToByteArraybyMemoryStream(Image image) {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

---

***Save Image to Disk method C#***

```
public static void ByteArrayToImageFilebyMemoryStream(byte[] imageByte) {
   try {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        image.Save(@"C:\Users\jycr753\Desktop\imageTest1.png");
   }
}
```

---

Convert to `byte[]` and send from ***Android*** Application.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, stream);
 byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
 File fl = new File( imagePath);
 FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream( fl );
 BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream( fi );
 bi.read( byteArray, 0, byteArray.length );
 OutputStream outs = sock.getOutputStream();
 outs.write( byteArray, 0, byteArray.length );
 outs.flush();
```

---

***Image from Console Application***
[image]

---

***Debugger in Save file method screen shot***

### [image]

***Manifest Permitions***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

***byte code***
Is there any issue if the C# application expect a `ASCII` encoding?

---

Any help of point me in the right direction it will be great, if there is the need to put more code, just ask :)

thanks community..

Comment: Any reason you can't send the data as a base64 encoded string?

Comment: is there any advantages in doing so?

Comment: Its simple. And portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not visible from the code provided how exactly does the C# open the other end of the socket stream and how does it read.

Very usual problem with reading socket streams is that you don't know when all data was received.

Network layer may signal there is some data multiple times. Without some protocol including marks of the meaning *data packet started* and *data packet ended* it is not possible to determine when whole PNG arrived, unless you use some all-or-nothing protocol - e.g. HTTP GET

Also the exact binary protocol must be agreed by both sides, e.g. [little or big endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618608/is-net-binaryreader-always-little-endian-even-on-big-endian-systems)

Need more data to provide better answer

Comment: Thanks, actually I end up using http post, since as you mentioned there was not way to find when he data had arrived completed, or if there was the need to wait for more, since the `base64` comment on top is really bad, you can only pass limited amount of data. but thanks for reply, its what i did it in the end :) \