# How to set the endian of a byte array in c#

Tags: c#, java

I've got some java codes like this:

```
   ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(length * 2);
   buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    for (short s : data)
      buffer.putShort(s);
```

How to convert it to `C#` code? 
basically, I don't know the how to work

```
  buffer.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

out in `C#`.

Any help is appreciate!

Comment: There's no ByteBuffer class in C#. What have you tried? Hint: Use [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A byte array is just a byte array. If you want to change endianness (swap byte order) you have to swap bytes yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a good place to start looking would be the msdn library docs specifically the `System.Convert` class can be used to convert value types to raw bytes and back again.

It looks like this question may help you as well:

[Is .NET BinaryReader always little-endian, even on big-endian systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618608/is-net-binaryreader-always-little-endian-even-on-big-endian-systems)