# C# -- BinaryReader and Little Endian

Tags: c#, binary, endianness

I have to read a binary file so I use this code:

```
static void ReadBin()
        {
            var sectors = new List<Sector>();
            using (var b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\\LOG.BIN", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                const int offset = 4096;
                const int required = 2;
                int pos = 0;
                var length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 640; i++)
                    {
                        pos = (offset*i)-2;
                        b.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        // Read the next 2 bytes.
                        byte[] by = b.ReadBytes(required);
                        sectors.Add(new Sector { Number = i, Position = pos, Type = Sector.SetTypeFromExadecimalString(ByteArrayToString(@by)) });
                        pos = pos + 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see the ByteArrayToString take the array of byte and write a string. The code of ByteArrayToString is:

```
    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return string.Format("0x{0}", hex.ToString().ToUpper());
    }
```

The machine that write the .bin file write it in LittleEndian. So following this StackOverflow thread "[Is .NET BinaryReader always little-endian, even on big-endian systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618608/is-net-binaryreader-always-little-endian-even-on-big-endian-systems)" I should be in "all" LittleEndian format (the ReadBytes and also the file generated by the machine).
The problem is that the function ByteArrayToString() gives me this result: 0xF0FF that is in BigEndian and not in LittleEndian (infact I suppose that I should receive instead 0xFFF0), because after that I have to decode a lot of data and I can't be sure of the consistency of result (I have nothing to compare), I don't want to have problem to decode the .bin file, how can I achieve to obtaing 0xFFF0?

Answer (score 1):

The endianness of `BinaryReader` only affects methods such as `ReadInt32`. It doesn't affect `ReadBytes` - that will *always* return you the bytes in the order in which they occur within the stream.

If you need a byte array (or a hex representation of it) in a particular ordering, you'll have to perform that ordering yourself.

If the file is meant to already *be* in the endianness you want, then it may well be that you're simply reading the wrong data. I wouldn't be entirely surprised by this - you're repositioning the underlying stream, which the `BinaryReader` may not be aware of. If it has read (say) 16 bytes into its buffer, it may not read from the stream again until you've read all of that buffer. I suggest you take `BinaryReader` out of the equation and just use `Stream` - it's not hard to write your own equivalent of `ReadBytes` which simply loops until it's either run out of data or read all the data you need.

Comment: Jom, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately something is quite strange...The snippet I provide is inserted inside a big project, well I have to read the signature of 640 sectors of a file. Every sector could be "signed" with 4 values. Well I can have only one sector signed by 0xFFF0 in Little Endian format. Now the others 639 sectors are just fine so it's quite impossible that I read the wrong data (otherwise also the others sector should be wrong). The tool that generate the file I'm sure that write in LittleEndian format. Perhaps when I copy it to my machines (by USB) the endian format change?

Comment: @pinguinone: That sounds very unlikely to me. You should look at the file with a binary file editor to check exactly what's there... and don't assume that anything is "quite impossible" until you've worked out what's actually going on.