# Why my 2 bytes (0x00 0x40) that should be 64 produce 16384 instead?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

Please see this file using `Hex Editor`:

[image: Hex dump]

I am reading the 2 bytes this way:

```
BinaryReader binaryReader;
int wlen = binaryReader.ReadUInt16();
```

When I read this 2 bytes my `BinaryReader.BaseStream.Position` is `14` but `wlen = 16384` and this should be 64. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll give you a hint... 0x4000 == 16384, you need to swap the bytes.

Comment: Show the *real* code. This fragment just generates a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: What @Ron said. Before your start parsing arbitrary bytes, learn about endianness.

Answer (score 3):

Your data file appears to be produced by some [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) writer, while `BinaryReader` reads data [assuming the little-endian representation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9618608/335858).

If you have control over the format of the file, changing the writer to produce little endian representation would let you avoid making changes to your C# program.

There are several ways to read big-endian data in .NET, too. You could use [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), but reversing the bytes manually is probably the most performant one:

```
public static short ToInt16Be(byte[] buf, int pos) {
    return (short)(buf[pos]<<8 | buf[pos+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`binaryReader.ReadUInt16()` reads using little endian.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readuint16(v=vs.110).aspx